# RelativeLayout with overlapping views

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I need to create a UI design like image below. I have used `RelativeLayout`, but the top `view` is hiding behind the `CardView`. I have tried so many ways, couldn't get it done.

[image]

**here is my code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/square_items">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_aboutus"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `ImageView` in `Cardview` so that elevation becomes equal for both. Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@color/red" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: working but how to add background color behind that imageview

Comment: change background of CardView : `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange"`